# Weak Convergence of a Sequence of Functions.

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, weak-convergence

To begin my question I wish to first clarify the definition of weak convergence FOR a sequence of functions.

We say that given sequence of functions, $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, such that each $f_n$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, CONVERGES WEAKLY to $f$ if:

$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)g(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx$,

for all $g(x)\in C[a,b]$.

Now, my real question is the following:

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of functions such that $e_n(x)=e^{-inx}$. Considering Parsevals Identity, what can be said about the weak convergence of $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

The first thing that came to mind was finding what the sequence converges to. Unfortunately I am having trouble evaluating

$\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{-inx}=\lim_{n \to \infty}cos(nx)-i\lim_{n \to \infty}sin(nx)$.

Either way, I try to relate to Parseval's identity which states that

$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|a_n|^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2$ such that $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx$

I realise that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx$ is familiar with my weak convergence definition, but I am unsure of how to progress from there. Since the limits from Parseval's Identity are rather fixed. I would assume that I am trying to show weak convergence for $e_n(x) \in C[-\pi,\pi]$.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum_n |a_n|^2$ *converges*, the terms must go to $0$, so $e^{inx}$ converges weakly to $0$ in $C[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Oh. I think I see what you're saying. Correct me if I am wrong: Since $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2$ is finite, therefore (as you stated) $\sum_{n= \infty}^{\infty}|a_n|^2$ converges. However, for such a series to converge, it will require $a_{n}$ to get smaller and smaller as $n$ approaches infinity. That is, $a_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx = 0$  under the same limit and thus it follows that   $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges weakly to 0 in $C[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @eXtremiity, yes, exactly.